# Vue Test Utils Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent

Tags: typescript, vue.js, unit-testing

I create a very simple test using `shallowMount` from `@vue/test-utils` in typescript and it show me a warning sounds `Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.` (Look Image). Have no idea what is it?

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Login from '@/views/Account/Login.vue'

describe('Login Page Test', () => {
    it('renders input for email', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Login)
        expect(wrapper.find("input"))
    })
})
```

Warning Capture
[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Uwp.png)

Comment: which typescript version do you use ?

Comment: I stumbled on this because I'm seeing the same thing.  I'm getting it in the `mount` function, but I'm sure it's related.  I was able to get things to work by building a brand new app (I'm using quasar), but am getting this error by trying to incorporate into an existing project.  As I can tell I have the same versions of all packages.